# PHPStorm slow on ONE specific CodeIgniter Model

Tags: sql, codeigniter, phpstorm

So my I swear by PHPStorm, I have been using it for over a year now and have had no issues up until now.

I have now come to *slight* problem in the form of sluggish editing.

I have a model file that is just under 4000 lines of code - nothing too big, but PHPStorm seems to be having some trouble with it. My other models seem to be just fine, but this one goes sluggish every few seconds while editing. Meaning, it will let me start typing and editing the code, but then it will freeze briefly for a few seconds and then complete the actions I entered... like lag.

I am assuming it has something to do with the fact that it's an SQL file since I have other control files that are larger.

Ultimate, I guess I can reduce the model in size to be separated into other models, but I would rather not.

Anyone else have experience with this?

Thanks
B

Comment: Personally, I'd call a 4000 line model about 5x too big.

Comment: Hmm yeah? Suppose I could break it down... still though. 4000 lines is not that much code  ...

Comment: File | Invalidate Caches and restart. It maybe helpful. But if not, for the root cause - you need to capture and analyze the CPU snapshot/thread dumps or easier: contact support.